# Program to capture data and address connected by a certain program

Tags: capture

I need to capture the remote addresses that a program connects to and the data that it sends and receives on Win 7. any suggestion for the program I can choose?

Comment: You have not accepted any answers (5 questions) and you may find some people reluctant to help you. Suggest you review them

Comment: So you need a packet sniffer? Try Wireshark ( http://www.wireshark.org/ ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Wireshark (which includes the libpcap packet capture library).  Wireshark provides a packet sniffer GUI and a number of analysis tools that will summarize traffic by endpoint(s), protocols, and other characteristics.  http://www.wireshark.org/